# Getting IOException receiving datagrampakcet through datagramsocket (Java)

Tags: java, udp, ioexception

I am trying to use a dagramsocket to send packages from a client to a server, but after spending some hours looking for information in StackOverflow and the offical documentation, I am still getting a IOException. 
I have a server, with recieve a sentence from a client, change the sentence and print the new sentence. Any idea why it is not working? Here is the code:

Client:

```
public class YodafyClienteTCP {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        byte []buferEnvio;
        byte []buferRecepcion=new byte[256];
        int bytesLeidos=0;

        // Nombre del host donde se ejecuta el servidor:
        String host="localhost";
        // Puerto en el que espera el servidor:
        int port=8989;
        DatagramPacket paquete;
        InetAddress direccion;

        // Socket para la conexión TCP
        DatagramSocket socketServicio;

        try {
            // Creamos un socket que se conecte a "host" y "port":

            socketServicio=new DatagramSocket();
            direccion = InetAddress.getByName(host);

            buferEnvio="Al monte del volcán debes ir sin demora".getBytes();

            paquete = new DatagramPacket(buferEnvio, buferEnvio.length, direccion, port);

            // Enviamos el array por el socket;
            socketServicio.send(paquete);
            System.out.println("Paquete enviado por el cliente.");

        socketServicio.close();

            // Excepciones:
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: Nombre de host no encontrado.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error de entrada/salida al abrir el socket.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Class which change sentence, invoked by server

```
public class ProcesadorYodafy {
    // Referencia a un socket para enviar/recibir las peticiones/respuestas
    private DatagramSocket socketServicio;


    // Para que la respuesta sea siempre diferente, usamos un generador de números aleatorios.
    private Random random;

    // Constructor que tiene como parámetro una referencia al socket abierto en por otra clase
    public ProcesadorYodafy(DatagramSocket socketServicio) {
        this.socketServicio=socketServicio;
        random=new Random();
    }


    // Aquí es donde se realiza el procesamiento realmente:
    void procesa(){

        // Como máximo leeremos un bloque de 1024 bytes. Esto se puede modificar.
        byte [] datosRecibidos=new byte[1024];
        int bytesRecibidos=0;
        DatagramPacket paquete;

        // Array de bytes para enviar la respuesta. Podemos reservar memoria cuando vayamos a enviarla:
        byte [] datosEnviar;


        try {
            // Lee la frase a Yodaficar:
            paquete = new DatagramPacket(datosRecibidos, datosRecibidos.length);
            socketServicio.receive(paquete);

            datosRecibidos = paquete.getData();
            bytesRecibidos = datosRecibidos.length;

            //yodaDo is just a method that changes some characters in the sentence
            String peticion=new String(datosRecibidos,0,bytesRecibidos);
            String respuesta=yodaDo(peticion);
            System.out.println("Here is your new sentence : " + respuesta);         

            socketServicio.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al obtener los flujos de entrada/salida.");
        }

    }
```

Server:

```
public class YodafyServidorIterativo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Puerto de escucha
        int port=8989;
        // array de bytes auxiliar para recibir o enviar datos.
        byte []buffer=new byte[256];
        // Número de bytes leídos
        int bytesLeidos=0;
        //Socket
        DatagramSocket socketServicio;

        try {
            // Abrimos el socket en modo pasivo, escuchando el en puerto indicado por "port"
            socketServicio = new DatagramSocket(port);
                        // Mientras ... siempre!
            do {
                //////////////////////////////////////////////////

                // Creamos un objeto de la clase ProcesadorYodafy, pasándole como
                // argumento el nuevo socket, para que realice el procesamiento
                // Este esquema permite que se puedan usar hebras más fácilmente.
                ProcesadorYodafy procesador=new ProcesadorYodafy(socketServicio);
                procesador.procesa();

            } while (true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error al escuchar en el puerto "+port);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You should post the *specific* error, not just "there was an error".

Comment: I said I am getting an IOexception when I recieve the package, I don't know more about the problem

Comment: That's because you're catching it and then failing to print out any of its information.

Comment: So, the exception is not because I am getting wrong the package, the error is somewhere else?

Comment: The exception has a *specific error message* and a stack trace, and you are discarding both. Use `e.printStackTrace()` in your catch block.

Comment: Din't know that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I was closing the datagramsocket in the class ProcesadorYodafy and opening the socket only once in the server, so in the following iteration of the loop, the datagramsocket was closed despite the fact I was sending there the package. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is a UDP connection, like mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730330/java-what-is-the-difference-between-serversocket-and-datagramsocket#27730390). Looking for the right connection you gonna find more fast the need documentation.

Second, probably your problem, whenever it is, is cause by:

1. One of your services isn't start or
2. You don't set the port of your client application and, thinking you're using this locally, can cause conflicts of resources.

Try to set the port of your client and make sure your server is started before start you client.

Comment: Server is started before running the client, that's sure. I use the same port in server, client and the java class wich change the sentence sent in the package. So, maybe there is a problem because of using localhost?

Comment: The problem is use the same port, and, when you try to catch a package, the port is already in use. Get different ports for client and server and try again.

Comment: Now the error dissapears, but server remains waiting for a package, whose datagramsocket is binded to port 8989, but client is sending through the same host with different port, 8990, so server can't get the package. Which is also strange is that client don't wait  in a recieve package statment, just continues and print the same sentence, with a small error. As a consequence, I don't know if it is using the same package, so, same data. or there is some kind of interference between packages